# WordPress enque scripts not working at all

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load the shipped version of jquery on my theme and it doesn't seem to like what I'm doing in my functions.php. I'm not sure why it won't load jquery nor my bootstrap.css file please have a look at my code below and let me know if you can guide me to a resolution:

```
function dbh_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() ); // it loads this script.

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', false, array(), null, true); // I want it to load in the footer

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true ); // not loading either.
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dbh_scripts' );
```

Please note that I want to load these in the footer and would rather not rely on a cdn for now. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you check wp_footer() maybe you missed that?

Comment: Dude I'm dumb that worked!

Comment: Cool.) Glad to help.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', false, array(), null, true);
```

Please try to remove this line and try it.